# How to use Bootstrap Switch control to send value to php script via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am populating a table from a database call. In the first column on every row I have a bootstrap 4 switch which is either set as checked or not depending on whether the records 'is-live' field is  set at 1.

I would like the user to be able to click the switch and set the record to live or not-live and for this to update the database and table seemlessly.
[image]

I know I need to use an AJAX call to do this but can't get my head around it as I'm really new to JQuery/AJAX.

I've got this far with the code and it is returning the success message but i'm stuck how I should be sending the input and row id to my php script.

I can write the php to update the db once the data is sent but the code looks like it isn't doing anything? I'm also not sure how do I return the success/fail to the AJAX script at the end of my php. Can I use a return true; or return false; to send the result to the AJAX script? I'm pretty sure that doesn't work.

And finally the script is in each table row which I think is pretty bad from a performance standpoint????

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#customSwitch<?php echo $voyage->voyage_id; ?>").on('change.bootstrapSwitch', function(e){
    var checkStatus = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
    request = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo URLROOT.'/admin/voyages/voyage-admin/updateLive/'; ?>',
      data: checkStatus,
    });
    // Callback handler that will be called on success
     request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
         // Log a message to the console
         console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
     });
     // Callback handler that will be called on failure
      request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          // Log the error to the console
          console.log(errorThrown);
      });
  });
});
```

And the PHP script being called via my controller / URL is just this at present...

```
public function updateLive() {
  return $_POST;
}
```

This is the table code (please excuse outdated script code):

```
<table id="trips" class="table table-bordered text-secondary">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-msp-lightgrey">
      <th width="5%">
        Active
      </th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Start
      </th>
      <th>
        End
      </th>
      <th>
        Type
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Places
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($data['voyageData'] as $voyage) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch<?php echo $voyage->voyage_id; ?>" value="1" <?php echo ($voyage->voyage_live) ? 'checked' : '';?>>
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch<?php echo $voyage->voyage_id; ?>"></label>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#customSwitch<?php echo $voyage->voyage_id; ?>").on('change.bootstrapSwitch', function(e){
                if($(this).is(':checked'))
                  alert('checked');

                else
                  alert('not checked');

              });
            });
            </script>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $voyage->voyage_name; ?>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($voyage->voyage_startDate)); ?>">
          <?php echo date('jS M Y', strtotime($voyage->voyage_startDate)); ?>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($voyage->voyage_endDate)); ?>">
          <?php echo date('jS M Y', strtotime($voyage->voyage_endDate)); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $voyage->voyagetype_name; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <?php echo $voyage->voyage_crewBerth; ?> | <?php echo $voyage->voyage_Afterguard; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Sort of... Will put where I have got too in an answer.

Comment: @MohammedShafeek just posted my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging and much expermentation I have a semi work around.

I have created a form which the table sits in and each bootstrap switch name/id is equal to the id of the record in the foreach loop. I then added a submit button in the footer of the table so it looks nice from a UX standpoint. Then I have my AJAX call send the server the data and I loop through setting each on/off as we go.

Still to do is work out how to make a featured voyage. I'd like the user to be able to click the star making that trip featured, but there should only be one featured trip so when clicking on a new trip the old should be unselected...

[image]

Code below:

```
<form class="switch" action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/admin/voyages/voyage-admin/updateLive" method="POST">
<table id="trips" class="table table-bordered text-secondary">
  <thead>
    <tr class="bg-msp-lightgrey">
      <th width="5%">
        Active
      </th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Start
      </th>
      <th>
        End
      </th>
      <th>
        Type
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
        Places
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($data['voyageData'] as $voyage) : ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="text-center">
            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
              <input value="1" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="<?php echo $voyage->voyage_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $voyage->voyage_id; ?>" <?php echo ($voyage->voyage_live) ? 'checked' : '';?>>
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?php echo $voyage->voyage_id; ?>"></label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo ($voyage->voyage_featured == 1) ? '<i class="fas fa-star text-msp-orange"></i> ' : '<i class="fas fa-star text-msp-lightgrey"></i> '; echo $voyage->voyage_name; ?>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($voyage->voyage_startDate)); ?>">
          <?php echo date('jS M Y', strtotime($voyage->voyage_startDate)); ?>
        </td>
        <td data-sort="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($voyage->voyage_endDate)); ?>">
          <?php echo date('jS M Y', strtotime($voyage->voyage_endDate)); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo $voyage->voyagetype_name; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <?php echo $voyage->voyage_crewBerth; ?> | <?php echo $voyage->voyage_Afterguard; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr class="bg-msp-lightgrey">
      <th>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-msp-orange text-white">UPDATE</button>
      </th>
      <th colspan="5">

      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</form>
```

The JQuery / Ajax call script is: (I found I had to destroy the old datatable table first then re-initialise it as I was getting strange behaviour on the update)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#trips').DataTable({
       "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
    });

    $('form.switch').on('submit', function() {
      var that = $(this),
          url = that.attr('action'),
          type = that.attr('method'),
          data = {};

      that.find('[name]').each(function(index,value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = $('#'+name).prop('checked')
        data[name] = value;
      });
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
          $('#statusMessage').toast('show');
          $('#trips').dataTable().fnDestroy();
          $('#trips').DataTable({
             "order": [[ 2, "asc" ]],
          });
        }
      });
      return false;
    });

  });
</script>
```

And this is my server side code:

```
public function updateLive() {
  if (!$this->permissionModel->checkSettingsPermission(get_class($this), $_SESSION['userGroup']) && $_SESSION['userGroup'] != 1) {
    flash('siteMessage', 'You do not have access to this page', 'bg-danger');
    redirect('register');
  }
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      if ($value == 'false') {
        $status = 0;
      } else {
        $status = 1;
      }
      $update = $this->voyageModel->status($key, $status);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Data table reload/draw is enough after Ajax done/success

Comment: Ok, will amend - what I'm trying to do now is how to highlight a featured voyage. I'd like the user to be able to click the star making that trip featured, but there should only be one featured trip so when clicking on a new trip the old one should be unselected or alternatively a loop un-feature'ing all the others